# css: обозначение единственного дочернего элемента через псевдоклассы

Tags: css, css3, html

Приветствую

У меня есть такая конструкция

```
<div class = 'block'>
    <div>data #1</div>
    <div>data #2</div>
</div>
```

В css свойства дочерних div заданы через псевдоклассы :first-child и :last-child

```
.block > div:first-child {}
.block > div:last-child {}
```

Иногда встречаются конструкции, где присутствует только один дочерний div и его свойства должны быть как у свойства последнего элемента

```
<div class = 'block'>
    <div>data #2</div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?
Метод

```
.block > div:first-child:last-child {}
```

не работает (хотя вроде как он логичен)

P.S.

```
.block > div:only-child {}
```

также не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему (странно, что сразу не разобрался, надо было чуть подумать):

```
.block > div:first-child:not(:only-child) {}

.block > div:only-child,
.block > div:last-child {}
```

Comment: можно даже упростить, убрав .block > div:only-child

Comment: only-child тут в целом лишний, можно просто block > div:first-child:not(:last-child)